# Exception raised while sending email to multiple users - win32com - Python

Tags: python, outlook

Here is my code:

```
import win32com.client as win32
outlook=win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
mail=outlook.CreateItem(0)
email_t4=a@xyz.com;b@xyz.com;c@xyz.com
mail.To='email_t4'
mail.CC='r@xyz.com'
mail.BCC='s@xyz.com'

mail.Subject='ABC'
mail.Body='XYZ'

mail.HTMLBody=<h1>Report</h1>

attachment4=r'C:\Users\r7\Downloads\frame4.html'

mail.Attachments.Add(attachment4)

mail.Send()
```

Here is exception message:

> ```
>  com_error  Traceback (most recent call
>  last) <ipython-input-26-ce3c12b7103e> in <module>()
>       30 mail.Attachments.Add(attachment4)
>       31 
>  ---> 32 mail.Send()  
>
>  ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py
>  in Send(self)
>
> com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (4096, 'Microsoft Outlook', 
> 'Outlook does not recognize one or more names. ', None, 0,
>  -2147467259), None)
> ```

Please help me here.

Answer (score 1):

I have updated your code to make it work. The errors were due to wrong quotes. I have added comments to the lines which are edited.

```
import win32com.client as win32
outlook=win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
mail=outlook.CreateItem(0)
email_t4='a@xyz.com;b@xyz.com;c@xyz.com' # Add quotes to value
mail.To=email_t4 # Remove quotes for teating as variable
mail.CC='r@xyz.com'
mail.BCC='s@xyz.com'

mail.Subject='ABC'
mail.Body='XYZ'

mail.HTMLBody='<h1>Report</h1>' # Quoted this as it was not valid syntax

attachment4=r'C:\temp\python\test.txt'

mail.Attachments.Add(attachment4)

mail.Send()
```

Comment: Are you using @xyz.com or some real address there?

Comment: I am using real address ..@xyz.com is just for example....When i am using single email, it works perfectly but when i m trying to put more than one email ids through variable then exception occured...

Comment: I have configured my Outlook with GMail. Ran above code exactly. It sent the mail which bounces obviously.